# RoR: Nested field in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, nested-forms

I have an application where the user can create a `gallery` to which he/she can attach some pictures. I use carrierwave for this purpose and it's structured as following.
Each `gallery` has many `pictures` and each `picture` has 1 `image`.

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true;
end
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :gallery
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Pictures are uploaded with following form

```
<%= form_for(@gallery, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.label :pictures %><br />
    <% if @gallery.pictures %>
        <ul class="form-thumbs clearfix">
        <% @gallery.pictures.each do |picture| %>
            <li>
                <%= image_tag(picture.image) %> 
                <%= link_to "Delete", gallery_picture_path(@gallery, picture), method: :delete %>
           </li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
    <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
<% end %>
```

and then processed with the following action

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)
        if @gallery.save
            if params[:images]
                params[:images].each do |image|
                    @gallery.pictures.create(image: image)
                end
            end
        end
    end
 end
```

This all works well, but now I'd like to add a nested field `:title`, so that when I open the form, and there are pictures uploaded, I can give a title to each picture. Could anyone explain me how to fit that in the existing form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be better doing the following:

```
#app/controllers/galleries_controller.rb
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @gallery = Gallery.new
       @gallery.pictures.build
   end

   def create
       @gallery = Gallery.new gallery_params
       @gallery.save
   end

   private

   def gallery_params
       params.require(:gallery).permit(:title, pictures_attributes: [:image, :title])
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to use the following:

```
#app/views/galleries/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @gallery do |f| %> 
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
   <%= f.fields_for :pictures do |p| %>
      <%= p.text_field :title %>
      <%= p.file_field :image %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will pass the attributes you need to your associated models.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rich. I get following error `undefined method 'title' for #<Picture::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f1ee01d7c10>` even though the `title` column is present in the `pictures` table

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `p.text_field :title` to test?

Comment: More or less, I can load the form now, but no picture is being created when I submit (I also don't see it in the action you wrote)

Comment: That's because it's a nested attribute - have you got a repo I could look at?

Comment: https://github.com/sjbuysse/Photography-portfolio-website
I gotta run now but will check in in a bit. Thank you so much for your time Rich

Comment: No problem - I looked at the repo, couldn't find any issues. Could you post your params?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92744/discussion-between-sjbuysse-and-rich-peck).